# control swf file starting frame

Tags: java, php, html, flash

in normal swf files, usually it plays from frame 1 till the end and then loop...

is it possible to use javascripts/any script to make it start play from, e.g. frame 10?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it would require the SWF to be fully loaded.

What I would do is create a pre-loader as the first frame which waits until the SWF has finished loading, you can then use the pre-loader to decide what frame to go to.

For this I'd have a default frame set as frame 2 (that's what frame 1 used to be) and then you may use either [FlashVars](http://blogs.adobe.com/pdehaan/2006/07/using_flashvars_with_actionscr.html) or [JavaScript](http://www.viget.com/inspire/bi-directional-actionscript-javascript-communication/) to tell the pre-loader which frame to choose. Personally, as you have PHP available, I'd use PHP to create the FlashVars dynamically on page generation.

Comment: @ jordanmoore, thanks, and can you show me the actual scripts? I also use php!

Comment: Here you go, let me know if you have any problems: http://jordanmoore.co.uk/examples/AS3/choosingTheFrameToPlayFromWithPHP.html#.Tqfr896Aq0s